# Decision tree indicating payoffs

Tags: cart, decision-theory

I need to draw a decision tree to represents these requirements :

The research and development manager in an old oil company, which is considering making some changes, lists the following courses of action for the company:

(i) Adopt a process developed by another oil company. This would cost €7 million in royalties and yield a net €20 million profit (before paying the royalty).

(ii) Carry out one or two (not simultaneously) alternative research projects :

(R1) the more expensive one has a 0.8 chance of success; net profit €16 million
and a further €6 million in royalties. If it fails there will be a net loss of €10 million.

(R2) the alternative research programme is less expensive but only has a 0.7
chance of success with a net profit of €15 million and a further €5 million in royalties. If it fails a net loss of €6 million will be incurred.

(iii) Make no changes. After meeting current operating costs the company expects to make a net €15 million profit from its existing process.
Failure of one research program would still leave open all remaining courses of action (including the other research programme).

I need also to indicate the different payoffs. This is what I've done so far :
[image]

I would like to be sure that I'm going in the right direction since I'm a beginner with decision trees. And then I need to decide the best course of action using Bayes, Maximax and Maximin rules.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If my decision tree fits the requirements ? As I am not very familiar with decision trees I would like to be sure I'm going in the good direction to determine the best action using Bayes, MAXIMAX and MAXIMIN rules.

Comment: What requirements?  I don't see anything in your question that appears to be requirements that would apply to decision trees.

Comment: `i) ii)` and `iii)` are the informations I have to build the decision tree.